# Python: Adding significant values to existing values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a python script that is extracting certain conditions which is as follows:

```
a  a1  1
       2
       3 
   a2  0
       1

b  b1  1
       2
   b2  0
       3
```

Until now what I was able to do is create a dictionary of first 2 columns and then create another dictionary for the 2nd and 3rd column. But I want all the 3 columns in one dictionary.

Here is the pseudo code that I have written so far:

```
mydict = {}
for lines in f:
    if 'a' or 'b' in lines:
        key = a

    if 'a1' in lines:
        value = a1
        mydict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```

and something similar for the second dictionary as well.

Please help me out !

expected output:

```
{ 'a' : [ 'a1': [1,2,3]],'b':['b1': [0,1]}
```

As I mentioned earlier, I want to create this dictionary from 2 existent dictionaries which look something like this

```
{'a': a1, 'b':b1}               #First Dictionary
{'a1': [1,2,3], 'b1': 123}      #Second Dictionary
```

I created these 2 dictionaries from a text file. And the code that is posted, is the code of how I extracted these 2 dictionaries.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What is the format of that example data input you show: is that the contents of a text file, are you implying some kind of data structure in Python, or something else? And what is the desired result from that example input?

Comment: Perhaps show an expected output?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

not the sexiest code on earth i admit

```
mydict = {}
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if not line:
        continue
    line = line.split()

    if len(line) == 3:
        l1_key = line.pop(0)
        mydict[l1_key] = {}
    if len(line) == 2:
        l2_key = line.pop(0)
        mydict[l1_key][l2_key] = []
    mydict[l1_key][l2_key].append(line.pop(0))
print(mydict)
```